# Images are not resizing correctly

Tags: css, amp-html

This is my test amp page where I was able to validate and make everything work except one thing - https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/iva/amp/tours.html

There is an issue with the yellow buttons under the header image. Even though they appear responsive there is a large gap under them that shows on small screens.

I figured the problem is:

```
<amp-img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/Trans.png" width="186" height="121" ></amp-img>
```

In order to make Trans.png responsive I tried adding layout="responsive" behind width="186" height="121"

This caused the button to disappear from the page though.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

My code where the images are is:

```
 <div align="center">
                <amp-img src="/Portals/0/tours-cat.jpg"  itemprop="image" width="740" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                <div class="ButtonContainer"> <a href="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/oahu/tours.htm">
                  <div class="OIslandButtons">
                    <amp-img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/Trans.png" width="186" height="121" ></amp-img>
                  </div>
                  </a> <a href="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/maui/tours.htm">
                  <div class="MIslandButtons">
                    <amp-img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/Trans.png" height="121" width="186" ></amp-img>
                  </div>
                  </a> <a href="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/kauai/tours.htm">
                  <div class="KIslandButtons">
                    <amp-img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/Trans.png" height="121" width="186" ></amp-img>
                  </div>
                  </a> <a href="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/bigisland/tours.htm">
                  <div class="BIslandButtons">
                    <amp-img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/Trans.png" height="121" width="186" ></amp-img>
                  </div>
                  </a> </div>
              </div>
```

And this is the CSS for the buttons:

```
.ButtonContainer {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.CatImg {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:auto;
}
.OIslandButtons {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/OahuB.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.OIslandButtons:hover {
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/OahuR.jpg);
}
.MIslandButtons {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/MauiB.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.MIslandButtons:hover {
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/MauiR.jpg);
}
.KIslandButtons {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/KauaiB.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.KIslandButtons:hover {
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/KauaiR.jpg);
}
.BIslandButtons {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/BigIslandB.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.BIslandButtons:hover {
    background-image:url(https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/BigIslandR.jpg);
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us the source code, or there's no way anyone will be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please apply width for image wrapper div.

```
.ButtonContainer div {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

**Notes:**

- Specify a CSS class for the particular div tag for applying the properties.
- Apply width percentage based on the margin and padding.

Comment: Thanks Ran, this made the buttons the correct size but didn't align them next to each other.

Comment: It may be because of the width percentage. Add the CSS properties to the given URL. So that I can see the issue.

Comment: Ok, please check now.

Comment: Apply for `.ButtonContainer div` not to `.ButtonContainer`

Answer (score 2):

After having a little play with the CSS in chrome I believe the issue lies with the img tags themselves and their parent amp-img. The amp-img has an element level width and height of 186px by 121px. I'm not sure what your javascript is but applying a width only to the underlying img, leaving the height dynamic and removing the amp-img width and heights worked to fix the size mismatch.

Unrelated, but there also seems to be a bug with the .Phone div where it's not changing its height when the responsive page changes, causing the .MainNav buttons to be pushed down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced the Trans.png with the buttons so I got rid of this overlay image. I removed the styles related to the buttons too so now the buttons resize correctly but they are one under another instead of next to each other, which is still not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height` attribute from below css class

```
@media screen and (max-width: 965px)
.Phone {
    //height: 147px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't have anything to do with this problem. I did remove it and issue is still there.